# Grails per-query one-to-one eager fetching

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Let's say you have face and nose, and you want to get the nose based on a faceId.

The Grails user guide tells you how to use mapping = { fetch:join } in a domain class to eagerly fetch the nose in one query whenever you fetch the face.

But I don't want to eagerly fetch all the time. I just want to do on this particular case to use one query instead of two. Can this be done on a per-query basis? Is there some way to do something like:
Face.get(faceId, [join:nose])?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean somthing link taht:

```
static fetchMode = [nose:'eager']
```

found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/fetchMode.html)

**Update:**

You can solve the problem with a criteria query. Here you can set the fetch mode in the query:

```
import org.hibernate.FetchMode as FM
    def c = MyDomain.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list {
        maxResults(10)
        firstResult(50)
        fetchMode("aRelationship", FM.EAGER)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that will configure it to fetch the nose eagerly every time. What if you only want to do it for one specific query?

Comment: @ Fletch I have updated my answer. Take also a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436144/eager-loading-queries-with-gorm-hibernate